# 'incorrect function' is returned from exec when calling java

Tags: inno-setup

I'm calling `cmd to excute java`, but the `resultcode` is always 1，after checking, I found it represents 'incorrect function'.
My code is like:

```
Exec('cmd', '/c C:\Program Files\jre\bin\java -version','' , SW_HIDE,   ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

I also call, the following code, it doesn't work either:

```
 Exec('cmd', '/c "C:\Program Files\jre\bin\java -version"','' , SW_HIDE,  ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

if I call the following code, it works

```
 Exec('cmd', '/c java -version','' , SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

**It seems the the space in the java path` can not be recognized**. Does anyone know how to correct it?

Comment: double quotes are required. please refer to http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt failed, due to a space in the file path, which was not enclosed by double quotes. Your second attempt failed because you've enclosed into double quotes except the file path also the passed parameter `-version`. And, in both cases you are missing `.exe` at the end of the application path.

You can try it this way instead:

```
Exec('cmd', '/c ""C:\Program Files\jre\bin\java.exe" -version"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

But, I'm missing here the reason for executing it through the `cmd` shell. I suppose you can do it directly by calling `java.exe` this way:

```
Exec('C:\Program Files\jre\bin\java.exe', '-version', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

Just one offtopic note, are you sure the `java.exe` will be always in `C:\Program Files\jre\bin\` ?

Comment: Note that `cmd /c` is weird when it comes to initial quotes.  In addition to quoting the filename you must also quote the entire command line; ie: `'/c ""C:\Program Files\...\java.exe" -version"'`.  (Of course, you should also be looking up the path to java instead of hard-coding it.)

Comment: Hi, I also found the reason of the problem is that one more pair of double quotes are required as Miral suggested. I look into the specific folder because it's under the installed application and we put jre into it.

Comment: I will fix it. @Miral, thanks for the hint! user1954461, still use rather the second way without `cmd` shell. Anyway, if this post resolved your question, you might [`consider to accept it`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541).

Comment: At first, I just call java application using Exec. Later, we need to redirect the output of the execution, so I use cmd to call java and add ">" to redirect output to a file. I there any other way to add log instead of modifying code?

Comment: I see. To your question, what did you mean by *other way to add log instead of modifying code* ? Did you mean another way to read console output ?

Comment: Yes, Miral's comment is the answer. But I do not know how mark comment as answer, could I just mark the whole post as answer? Actually, I found the answer, but it's not allowed to answer my request within 6 hours, I just post it as a comment:). Thank you, you guys are a big help when I have problem when programming!

Comment: Relating to "add log", I mean using log4j or other log mechanism to log info. The code already use: System.out.println(). So we want to take advantage of it.

Comment: I have fixed my original post according to Miral's comment (and there's also an alternative, more straight answer to the original question, since you've not mentioned that you're relying on `cmd`; if one strictly don't need `cmd` shell, it's better to avoid its use), but do as you like :-) To your second comment, sorry I'm not familiar with Java at all.